# Where to store static string data in xml form?

Tags: android, coding-style

I have a static string, in my android application, which is in xml format. I want to store the file in some variable. One way is to store that in res/string.xml folder. But when I am doing this I got this error

```
The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
```

Other way is to initialize a string variable with that xml string. But, I guess, that is not a good way to do.

My xml string is as given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<DumpStudentData xmlns="http://www.milpahost.com/">
<objUserRequest>
<CourseId xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Milpa.Server.WcfService.BusinessObjects">6</CourseId>
<MachineId xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Milpa.Server.WcfService.BusinessObjects">8qK6HM8LuAXq8bLROSsVjZ5u8Adn3IvvvLXDDe85Rq3Zi1hIQZZY8o6eyJPCYIgqdDRgRgqbK6RAdtJ3GXU73Q==</MachineId>
<ProviderId xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Milpa.Server.WcfService.BusinessObjects">6</ProviderId>
<StudentId xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Milpa.Server.WcfService.BusinessObjects">13</StudentId>
<UserLiveInternalId xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Milpa.Server.WcfService.BusinessObjects">t=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&amp;p=</UserLiveInternalId>
<UserLiveLoginId xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Milpa.Server.WcfService.BusinessObjects">pengalaus66@hotmail-int.com</UserLiveLoginId>
</objUserRequest>
<listOfDumps><ContentDump><ContentId>1</ContentId><XmlContent>&lt;DoubtsStore xmlns="http://www.milpahost.com/DoubtsStore.xsd" /&gt;</XmlContent></ContentDump><ContentDump><ContentId>2</ContentId><XmlContent>&lt;AssessmentProficiency xmlns="http://www.milpahost.com/AssessmentProficiency.xsd"&gt;
```

How can I store this string as a constant?

Comment: What about storing this xml file as an asset file?

Comment: @Yury Yeah that is one way, but I'll not prefer that, since reading the file will make the app slow

Comment: Do you have any numbers about this? Did you try to read from asset file and measure the time?

Comment: I didn't tried that. But we dont want to include anything in the assets folder. There are some restrictions for the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried enclosing the string in CDATA ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="string_name">
<![CDATA[

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope>
       ....
    </soap:Envelope>

]]>        
    </string>

</resources>
```